# Analysis Method to Deblurring Image

Tags: image-processing

To deblur the image. usually we consider the model
$$B=A(X)+e,$$
where $X$ is the expected image, $A$ is the convolution/matrix action and $B$ is the blurred image.

I know there are some matrix-methods to deal with the above case, e.g. in the book Deblurring Images: Matrices, Spectra, and Filtering.

**Q**: Are there some pde model/ functional model to understand the deblurring problem in mathematics. In other words, could anyone give some reference about the analytic methods to deblurr the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume the image to be recovered is an $m \times n$ array of real numbers.  A very common method is to solve a convex optimization problem such as
$$
\operatorname{minimize}_{X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}}  \quad \frac12 \| A(X) - B \|^2 + \gamma \| Dx \|_1 
$$
where $D$ is a discrete gradient operator (in which case we're using "total variation regularization") or some sparsifying transformation such as a wavelet transformation.  The norm $\| \cdot \|_1$ is just the usual $\ell_1$-norm, and $\| \cdot \|$ is the Frobenius norm.

Here is a great tutorial paper on how to solve image processing problems like this one: "[An introduction to continuous optimization for imaging](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01346507/document)" by Chambolle and Pock.  It was published in 2016.

Comment: @DLIN I edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: How about the blind deblurring model? Could you also give a reference?